# Range Filter by within array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I want to make shift parser helper which is generate time of work shift, below is shift rule

```js
  let shift_rule = [
    {
      shift: '07-12',
      start: 7,
      finish: 12
    },
    {
      shift: '12-17',
      start: 12,
      finish: 17
    },
    {
      shift: '17-22',
      start: 17,
      finish: 22
    },
  ];
```

If time shift is `timeStart = 7`, `timeFinish = 17`

Expected output:

```js
[
    {
      shift: '07-12',
      start: 7,
      finish: 12
    },
    {
      shift: '12-17'
      start: 12,
      finish: 17
    },
]
```

I'd already try to solve with this code

```js
shift_rule
    .map((time) => ((timeFinish > time.start)) && time)
    .filter(item => typeof item !== 'boolean');
```

But when filter was `time.start = 17` , `timeFinish = 22`, it show:

```js
[
    {
      shift: '07-12',
      start: 7,
      finish: 12
    },
    {
      shift: '12-17',
      start: 12,
      finish: 17
    },
    {
      shift: '17-22',
      start: 17,
      finish: 22
    },
  ]
```

Hope can be solved with ES6 Functional

Comment: First, its always better and cleaner to use filter first and then use map. `typeof item !== 'boolean'` is kinda a bad check. Second, in your map function, you are not checking for `timeStart` with anything. Should it not be `time.start >= timeStart && time.finish <= timeFinish`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for overlapping time ranges by checking that the start of each range is before the end of the other (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)). You can implement that code in a filter and then use map to return just the shift name:

```js
let shift_rule = [
  { shift: '07-12', start: 7, finish: 12 },
  { shift: '12-17', start: 12, finish: 17 },
  { shift: '17-22', start: 17, finish: 22 } 
];

const filter_shifts = (rules, timeStart, timeFinish) =>
  rules.filter(s => s.start < timeFinish && s.finish > timeStart).map(s => s.shift);

console.log(filter_shifts(shift_rule, 7, 17));
console.log(filter_shifts(shift_rule, 17, 22));
```